# How to check if an Excel Range is empty in C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I want to check if a range (cells in row * column) is empty using C#. I can traverse through cells, but any bettter and faster way ? Any method to get range from selected/active cell and number of rows and column ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347276/in-vsto-excel-how-to-detect-data-in-cells

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suppose that [Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.counta.aspx) works not only with sheets but with any Range argument:

> Use CountA to count the number of cells that contain data in a range
>   or array.
>
> A value is any type of information, including error values and empty
>   text (""). A value does not include empty cells.
>
> If an argument is an array or reference, only values in that array or
>   reference are used. Empty cells and text values in the array or
>   reference are ignored.