# Add values to excel file

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I have a problem, and again need your help.

So i'm creating application, that will add some values to excel from dataGridView.

I created this:

```
    OpenFileDialog fd2 = new OpenFileDialog();
        fd2.Filter = "excel datoteka(*.xls)|*.xls";
        fd2.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (fd2.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {

        Excel.Application objExcel = new Excel.Application();
        objExcel.Visible = true;
        string path = fd2.FileName;
        Excel.Workbook objBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(path,                                                                                                                              System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        Excel.Worksheet objSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)objBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Range objRange;
        objRange = objSheet.get_Range("A15","V40");
        objRange.Value = "74";
        objRange.set_Value(System.Reflection.Missing.Value,7);

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error");
    }
```

I need that program gets range if field is empty. and objrange.set_value must have data from datagrid.

Thx for your help.

Comment: As for checking if the range is empty please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854491/how-to-check-if-an-excel-range-is-empty-in-c-sharp as for the second question about getting the data from a datagridview. Can you explain what your problem is?

Comment: all i get in excel file is 7

`objRange.set_Value(System.Reflection.Missing.Value,7);`

I have datagridview to check excel values.

So my problem is: i need that all the values from datagrid go to other excel.

Comment: so just manually add the values from your datagridview. Iterate through all columns and rows and use the objRange.set_Value(missing, dataGridView[i][j]); (assuming i/j are the loop variables) and don't forget to always get a new range for every value

Comment: `objRange.set_Value(System.Reflection.Missing.Value,dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].ToString());


              for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
              {
                  for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
                  {
                      DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
                      objSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value;`now i get strange output the info gets to excel but, other fields get: DataGridViewTextBoxCell { ColumnIndex=0, RowIndex=0 }

Comment: try dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[‌​j].Value

Comment: i have only one more problem, and that is to check if excel row is empty, i made something like this:

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44683/discussion-between-user2768054-and-lukas-hafliger)