# How to copy cell formatting and style

Tags: excel, vba, object, cell-formatting

Guys if I use the following code:

```
dim Defaultcol As Long

Defaultcol = Sheets("Whatever").Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
```

I can get the color formatting from a cell.

Could I also write something like

```
dim FullFormat as object (Or dim FullFormat as cellformat)

set FullFormat =  Sheets("Whatever").Cells(1, 1).formats
```

and get all the formats of a cell in one object?

or maybe

```
dim sourcecell as cell

set sourcecell = Sheets("Whatever").Cells(1, 1)
```

and then have property `sourcecell.formats` that I could use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451511/vsto-getting-excel-cell-properties-in-bulk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to copy the basic formatting of a cell using [MSND's Guide](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/copy-formats-from-one-cell-or-range-to-another-HP005199434.aspx)

While the above may be a workaround when it comes to VBA there is no direct way of copying cells Styles/Formatting.

It's true that the [`Style` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196938.aspx) stores the styles but no methods exist (*at least I am not aware of any*) which allow you to use the `Style` object to copy and apply formatting between cells.

There is a workaround it using VBA

One way is to use `String` arguments to copy *`from`* and *`to`* ie.

```
Private Sub CopyFormatting(fromRng As String, toRng As String)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim tmpVal
    tmpVal = Range(toRng)
    Range(fromRng).Copy Range(toRng)
    Range(toRng) = tmpVal
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

and Call it like

```
Sub Main()
    CopyFormatting "A1", "A10"
End Sub
```

and this will copy the formatting and retain the Value unlike lots of online guides which only copy and paste the cell

---

A better way would be to pass reference to `Range` objects as it allwos you to use it in between different sheets etc.

Example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Set rng1 = Sheets(1).Range("B3")
    Set rng2 = Sheets(2).Range("A1")

    CopyFormatting rng1, rng2
End Sub

Private Sub CopyFormatting(fromRng As Range, toRng As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim tmpVal
    tmpVal = toRng
    fromRng.Copy toRng
    toRng = tmpVal
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Very Nice!...........an alternative could be to dynamically create a **Style** based on the source range formatting and then have it available for use later.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I'd export the style as an XML - ie. a string that could be extracted/imported using a template for that. It's to huge of a topic to go over that now but it'd be possible

Answer (score 1):

The Object that captures or encapsulates the full formatting of a cell is its **Style**.

See **VBA Help**.

Comment: ok so how to copy the style from one cell to another which is the greater part of the question :)

Comment: @mehow If we know, in advance, that a particular formatting is to be applied, then a **Style** can be created and then applied.   If we have not prepared, we can rely on PasteSpecialFormats.

Comment: I think the `Style` class is a bit useless (requires iteration over all properties in order to copy properly - which further requires you to override the class in order to be able to iterate all properties <= lots of work) so I provided an alternative way I tend to think when I have to copy formatting/styling between cells.