# Find which cells have a certain colour and list them

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating an English activity where you practice letters and numbers by having you draw a picture using grid coordinates that I say out loud. The top row has letters and the left column has numbers, and using a combination of both, you can specify what colour is in which cell.

Doing this in excel, I have been drawing the pixel images manually (by printing out images and drawing boxes then coloring background colours in excel cells) and then writing out the answer key (A list of black cells in A, B C etc., Red cells in A, B, C etc.) manually. This has been okay but does come with errors sometimes.

I would like to know a way to list which cells have a certain background colour in them. Ultimately, it would be great if I could list it like the following example:

- Black
- A: 1, 2, 3, 4
- B: 4, 5, 6
- C: 4, 5, 6
- etc.

I heard formulas won't work with excel and I would need to use a macro, which is something I have no experience with. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate, such as https://stackoverflow.com/q/8451511/4961700

Comment: Hi Gerhard. Can you please posta an example image or sheet?

Comment: You can use Autofilter to filter by background color (manually or using VBA: `.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor` if this meets your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Excel workbook has at least one sheet containing the coloured cells (I will refer to that one as "Sheet1") and one extra where to display the result of the query, let's call it "Sheet2", a code listing the coloured cells' addresse could look like this:

```
Sub ColorIndex()

    Dim RNG         As Range    'the address of the cell you want to check
    Dim lnCol       As Long     'the column of the cell looked at
    Dim lnRow       As Long     'the row of the cell looked at
    Dim c           As Long     'the column on Sheet2 and...
    Dim r           As Long     'the row on Sheet2 where the address of the coloured cell is written to

    c = 1
    r = 1

    For lnCol = 1 To 100  'adjust if necessary, see below

        For lnRow = 1 To 100  'adjust if necessary, see below
        Set RNG = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lnRow, lnCol)

            If RNG.Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, c) = RNG.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) 'Address of the coloured cell on Sheet1 as Row x / Column y
                r = r + 1 'next match written in next row
                ElseIf RNG.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, c+1) = RNG.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
            End If

        Next lnRow

    Next lnCol

End Sub
```

Note this code checks rows/columns 1 to 100 only. If you have a larger range to check, adjust the number accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ① `iC` is never used! You can remove that variable completely. ② For additional colors you would not copy the whole loop! One loop is enough, you would just use an `ElseIf RNG.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then` for example and a second row counter `r`. Otherwise it takes double the time with an additional loop.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help! I will bring it to work with me after the holiday period ends here.