# VSTO c# Check if a cell is null

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

If one has a reference to a cell, how does one check if it is null?

Pseudo Code:

```
Excel.Range cell = (Excel.Range)MyRange.Cells[1, 1];
if (cell.value2.IsNull) { Stuff }
else { Other Stuff }
```

Unfortunately, `IsNull` does not exist.

Comment: `cell.value2 == null`? (I'm sorry if that's a useless remark, I don't know anything about excel interop)

Comment: Looks like you want the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347276/in-vsto-excel-how-to-detect-data-in-cells

Comment: <shame>actually cell.value2==null might be what I need </shame>

Comment: Yes, in excel interop you check the Value2 == null property, in some cases you can even get string.Empty, depeneding on the format, but you can write a simple function that will check for both.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were overthinking. `Range.Value2` returns an object. So if you'd like to check for null reference, just do

```
if(Range.Value2 == null)
{
  //blah blah
}
else
{
  //blah blah
}
```

You probably should check out the online API documentation a bit more.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms262200(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms262200%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
if (mWSheet1.Cells[z, y + 3].Value2 != null)
```

or

```
orderPc.ManufactureDate = Convert.ToString(mWSheet1.Cells[z, y + 3].Value2);
```