# Detect blank Excel cell using interop.excel in C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I'm trying to parse text from an Excel doc in C#. The problem is that I can't find a way to detect (and ignore) blank cells.

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in Visual Studio 2010 C#. I can't skip blank cells so my program will consequentially store blank values.

---

I have defined my woorksheet the following way:

`Excel.Application exApp = OpenExcel(); String mySheet = @"C:\sheet.xlsx"; Excel.Workbook wb = exApp.Workbooks.Open(mySheet); Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Sheets[1];`

I access my cells by `ws.Cells[row, col]`. And I've tried different approaches. To name a few:

```
ws.Cells[row, col].Value2 == null
ws.Cells[row, col].Value == null
ws.Cells[row, col].Value == ""
```

And also using the Range object explicitely
`Excel.Range rng = ws.Cells[row, col]`
To use `rng.Value2`

Depending on which approach I use I get different errors, Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC is one of them.

Comment: @user1274820 You can't convert `null` to a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In VSTO Excel, how to detect data in cells?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347276/in-vsto-excel-how-to-detect-data-in-cells)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28452164/4551007

Please seee this for a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use SpecialCells. E.g. the code below sets the value of all empty cells to zero (vba code).

```
Range("e11:g16").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = 0
```

Or you can easily loop all empty cells like this:

```
For Each item In Range("e11:g16").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
   '...
Next
```

In the same logic, if you want to loop through all cells which are not empty:

```
 For Each item In Range("g10:h11").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        '...
 Next
```

Comment: This helped but does not solve my main problem which is that the blank cells are still there. 'Excel.Range row = ws.Rows[1];
            Excel.Range rng = row.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants);' works perfectly to select the non-empty cells. I can use rng.Select and see them in my sheet. But when I transfer the cell values to an array, the blank cell is still there. Its really weird because rng.Count is the same as the non-empty cell count. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could try to loop through rng and add each item to a list. Then copy list into array if you need an array.

Comment: I've sort of tried that but the problem is that the range when I select it only highlight non-empty cells in the sheet. And its count is equal to non-empty cells but still if I print each range cell (rng[1, i].value.ToString()) one cell in the range is still blank. I don't see how it adds up.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the Text property of the Range object...

```
rng.Text == String.Empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (ws.IsEmpty(Cells[row, col]))
```

I don't exactly remember if I got the syntax right for porting to Excel from .NET, but this is the command I use in a VB macro from within Excel.

you can also try IsNumeric(Cells[row,col].Value)

The default value for Excel cells is Empty (but I can't find the MSN link to verify this!)

See: [What is the difference between =Empty and IsEmpty() in VBA (Excel)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522323/what-is-the-difference-between-empty-and-isempty-in-vba-excel)