# Excel Range in C# using interop.Excel. Range both empty and not empty?

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have a Excel sheet that looks like this.
|A1|B1| "BLANK" |D1|E1|F1|
I.e. only the first row is populated and the third column is blank. I parse this in C# using interop.excel in the following way:

```
        Excel.Application exApp = OpenExcel();
        String mySheet = @"C:\c#\rapport.xlsx";
        Excel.Workbook wb = exApp.Workbooks.Open(mySheet);
        Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range row = ws.Rows[1];
```

I create a new range only containing the non-empty cells in row 1 by

```
        Excel.Range rng = row.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants);
```

Now: if I use `rng.Select` all the non-empty cells in my sheet is selected. And if I use `rng.Count` it will return 5, which is the number of non-empty cells in my sheet. But still when I print cell by cell using:

```
Console.WriteLine(rng[1,i].Value.ToString());
```

It shows that rng[1, 1-2] contains "A1 and B1", this is nice. But
rng[1, 3] is empty or null. And rng[1, 4-7] contains D1-F1.

How is this possible?

My main goal is to store all non-empty values in a string array. But I can't select the right values because my range rng is both empty and non-empty is some weird way.

Comment: You need to iterate the cells in rng using a foreach construction. Using the `.Item` method as you are is not restricted to the actual cells in the range - it's just relative to the first cell of the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it! However I didn't use the  .Item method to store the values as Rory suggested suggested. Thnx Rory!

```
        string[] str = new String[rng.Count];
        int i = 0;

        foreach (Excel.Range cell in rng.Cells)
        {
            str[i] = cell.Value.ToString();
            i++;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
            Console.WriteLine(str[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
ws.Columns.ClearFormats();
ws.Rows.ClearFormats();
```

to be sure your Range excludes formatted but empty cells.

Another try could be to get :

```
Excel.Range rng = row.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants,Type.Missing);
```

Comment: Thank you but it didn't help. I still get a null value stored in my rng. I don't get it. It clearly highlights all non-empty cells in the sheet it also says it only contains 5 non-empty cells butt still, the third position in rng stores a null.